# автоматическое увеличение числа jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

на сайте есть 3 числа которые должны анимированно увеличиваться от 0 до, например, 100
т.е.

```
<h3 id="counter">0</h3>
<h3 id="counter1">0</h3>
<h3 id="counter2">0</h3>
```

и

```
setTimeout(function(){
                $('#counter').text('0');
                $('#counter1').text('0');
                $('#counter2').text('0');
                setInterval(function(){

                    var curval=parseInt($('#counter').text());
                    var curval1=parseInt($('#counter1').text().replace(' ',''));
                    var curval2=parseInt($('#counter2').text());
                    if(curval<=32){
                        $('#counter').text(curval+1);
                    }
                    if(curval1<=42){
                        $('#counter1').text(sdf_FTS((curval1+1),0,' '));
                    }
                    if(curval2<=28){
                        $('#counter2').text(curval2+1);
                    }
                }, 2);
```

если я в этом коде убираю +1 т.е. не curval1+1 а curval1, тогда этой анимации нет, как можно еще по другому реализовать эту анимации увеличения чисел?

Comment: https://codepen.io/shivasurya/pen/FatiB

Comment: то что нужно, огромное спасибо